# Adding new row in DataGridView doesn't add to BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, bindinglist

I've a little problem using a `DataGridView` with `AllowUserToAddRows` set to `True` that is binding to a list (`BindingList<State>`).

When adding a new row through the GUI, the row isn't added to the `BindingList`.

I've a entity which contains a collection with other entities. For example: Country contains States. So, the new row in datagridview isn't added in the StateCollection on country object.

That's is how I add the `BindingList` to the `DataGridView`:

```
var bl = new BindingList<State>(country.StatesCollection.ToList<State>());
grdData.DataSource = bl;
```

Properties:

```
EditMode is set to EditOnKeystrokeOrF2
```

If more data is needed, please ask me.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a `RowAdded` event or something similar. You might need to react to that.

Comment: Hi, if i catch the RowsAdded event, the DataBoundItem is null, and is fired when is clicked new Row...

Comment: There is a [`UserAddedRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You mean when you click on the new row with * on the left, its not letting you edit?

Comment: rageit: yes, in that row

Comment: With UserAddedRow, has the same behavior that RowsAdded

Comment: Check if your gird is not enabled and see what is the EditMode set.

Comment: If your grid or any of its containers are not Enabled keystrokes will not work. But other than that everything looks good to me. You should be able to type on the new row to add text to the fields.

Comment: i can add new row, but that row isn't added to the binding list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your code, I initialized `context.MyEntities` with 3 `MyEntity` objects.

After binding, the `DataGridView` shows the 3 rows as well as the expected `* NewRow`. Thus:

```
context.MyEntities.Length == 3 // .Count or .Length depending on data structure
((BindingList<MyEntity>)grdData.DataSource).Count == 3
grdData.Rows.Count == 4
```

After entering data into the `NewRow` within the GUI, the `DataGridView` now shows 4 rows as well as the expected `* NewRow`. Thus:

```
context.MyEntities.Length == 3
((BindingList<MyEntity>)grdData.DataSource).Count == 4
grdData.Rows.Count == 5
```

Adding an item to the `DataGridView` *did indeed* add the object to the `BindingList` source, but not to the actual `context.MyEntities` source, which I assume is where you are expecting to see this new item added.

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because of this line:

```
var bl = new BindingList<MyEntity>(context.MyEntities.ToList<MyEntity>());
```

You are declaring a **new** object for your binding. Even if `context.MyEntities` is also a `BindingList<MyEntity>` (I doubt since that would negate the reason for the above line of code), it will not be updated with the new entry. For the desired behavior, you have two options:

1. Change `context.MyEntities` type to `BindingList<MyEntity>`, then simply change your binding to:

   ```
   grdData.DataSource = context.MyEntities;
   ```
2. Handle `DataGridView.RowsAdded` and manually update `context.MyEntities` by *a) adding the new item* or *b) refreshing the original object*:

   ```
   private void grdData_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
   {
       var source = ((BindingList<MyEntity>)grdData.DataSource);
       context.MyEntities = // source converted to the correct Enumerable type
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.... but i made a mistake when i wrote the question... so sorry. Right now, i'm editing the question.... i don't used the context directly.

Comment: No problem.  Aside from property name changes, it appears your question is essentially the same and barring the same name changes in the answer it should still be applicable.